# Access embedded device UI running on top of QT Webkit using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, qtwebkit

I have a embedded device which runs QT Webkit displaying GUI. I need to access the device QTWebKit browser using the QTWebDriver. Not seeing much examples on how to go ahead. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to start QtWebDriver in the same proces as the QApplication starting your gui.

In order to do this you need to link you app with the QtWebDriver's libs and headers.

For example to add webdriver suport to the QT5.5/Src/qtbase/examples/widgets/mainwindows/mainwindow example, first modify mainwindow.pro:

```
+++ mainwindow.pro  2017-01-13 15:06:53.048081230 -0800
@@ -1,6 +1,17 @@
 TEMPLATE = app

-QT += widgets
+QT += widgets quick
+INCLUDEPATH += /home/user/qtwebdriver/out/dist/desktop/release/Test
+INCLUDEPATH += /home/user/qtwebdriver/out/dist/desktop/release/h
+LIBS += -L/home/user/qtwebdriver/out/dist/desktop/release/libs
+LIBS += -lchromium_base -lWebDriver_core -lWebDriver_extension_qt_base -lWebDriver_extension_qt_quick -lWebDriver_extension_qt_quick_web -lWebDriver_extension_qt_web
+DEFINES += QT_NO_SAMPLES="1"
```

Second include the  webdriver headers in your app and call `wd_setup(argc, argv)`

```
+++ main.cpp    2017-01-13 15:45:33.663764896 -0800
@@ -32,6 +32,7 @@
 ****************************************************************************/

 #include "mainwindow.h"
+#include "Headers.h"

 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QPainterPath>
@@ -149,6 +150,7 @@ int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     QMap<QString, QSize> customSizeHints = parseCustomSizeHints(argc, argv);
+    wd_setup(argc, argv);
     MainWindow mainWin(customSizeHints);
```

(You can flag this additional code to be included only in test builds)

Then run your GUI. By default webdriver start on port 9517.

You can the use Selenium's RemoteWebDriver to connect to QtWebDriver

```
 DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
 //Start WebDriver by reusing existing widget UI
 capability.setCapability("browserStartWindow", "*");
 driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://remotehost:9517"), capability)
 selectWindow("http");
 etc...

 private String selectWindow(String protocol) {
    Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

    for (Iterator<String> iterator = windowHandles.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        String w = iterator.next();
        driver.switchTo().window(w);
        if (driver.getCurrentUrl().startsWith(protocol))
            return w;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The `browserStartWindow` capability instructs QtWebDriver to select the first window it finds.

If your WebView is embedded into native widgets yo will need to iterate on all the window handles and select the window which has html content, hence the use of `selectWindow` :

Once the correct (sub)window selected it is regular selenium testing.

You can find this info in the QtWebDriver wiki:

- https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver/wiki/Hybridity-And-View-Management
- https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver/wiki/Use%20QtWebDriver%20to%20run%20your%20application

Comment: can the webkit URL be accessed via browser on my PC?

Comment: @python101, what do you mean? If you mean gan you get the current URL of the WebDriver from Selenium, then yes, use `driver.getCurrentUrl`. If you want to inspect the page currently open by the WebDriver then pass the `-wi-server`arg to `wd_setup`. You will then be able to use the remote web inspector on you PC by opening `http://remotehost:9222`. See https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver/wiki/Command-Line-Switches for the list of webdriver args.

Comment: that's pretty much what i need. Thanks